# Matching data across 2 columns using R

Tags: r

I have 2 columns of data and I want to determine and count the number of mismatches.  I used:

```
c <-rep ("p*02:01:01:01+p*02:01:02:01", 6)
d <-rep ("p*02:01:02:01+p*02:01:01:01", 6)
y <-data.frame(c,d, stringsAsFactors = F)
y
#                             c                           d
# 1 p*02:01:01:01+p*02:01:02:01 p*02:01:02:01+p*02:01:01:01
# 2 p*02:01:01:01+p*02:01:02:01 p*02:01:02:01+p*02:01:01:01
# 3 p*02:01:01:01+p*02:01:02:01 p*02:01:02:01+p*02:01:01:01
# 4 p*02:01:01:01+p*02:01:02:01 p*02:01:02:01+p*02:01:01:01
# 5 p*02:01:01:01+p*02:01:02:01 p*02:01:02:01+p*02:01:01:01
# 6 p*02:01:01:01+p*02:01:02:01 p*02:01:02:01+p*02:01:01:01

y$c == y$d

# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

But the output should be TRUE for all 6 rows because I want to know whether p*02:01:01:01 and p*02:01:02:01 is present in both columns c and d, I don't care if p*02:01:01:01 or p*02:01:02:01 is before or after the plus sign.

Data frame with other examples added. Also mapply formula only works for dataframes but not on my imported csv file.

> y

```
                        c                            d
1 p*02:01:01:01, p*02:01:02:01 p*02:01:02:01, p*02:01:01:01
2 p*02:01:01:01, p*02:01:02:01 p*02:01:02:01, p*02:01:01:01
3 p*02:01:01:01, p*02:01:02:01 p*02:01:02:01, p*02:01:01:01
4 p*02:01:01:01, p*02:01:02:01 p*02:01:02:01, p*02:01:01:01
5 p*02:01:01:01, p*02:01:02:01 p*02:01:02:01, p*02:01:01:01
6 p*02:01:01:01, p*02:01:02:01 p*02:01:02:01, p*02:01:01:01
7 p*02:01:01:01, p*02:01:01:01    p*02:01:01:01, p*02:01:13
8      p*02:134, p*02:01:01:01    p*02:01:01:01, p*02:01:13
9 p*01:01:01:01, p*02:01:01:01 p*01:01:01:01, p*02:01:01:01
```

Comment: Perhaps `mapply(function(x,y) all(x==y), lapply(strsplit(y$c, "[+]"), sort), lapply(strsplit(y$d, "[+]"), sort))#[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
c <-rep ("p*02:01:01:01+p*02:01:02:01", 6)
d <-rep ("p*02:01:02:01+p*02:01:01:01", 6)
y <-data.frame(c,d, stringsAsFactors = F)
y
#                             c                           d
# 1 p*02:01:01:01+p*02:01:02:01 p*02:01:02:01+p*02:01:01:01
# 2 p*02:01:01:01+p*02:01:02:01 p*02:01:02:01+p*02:01:01:01
# 3 p*02:01:01:01+p*02:01:02:01 p*02:01:02:01+p*02:01:01:01
# 4 p*02:01:01:01+p*02:01:02:01 p*02:01:02:01+p*02:01:01:01
# 5 p*02:01:01:01+p*02:01:02:01 p*02:01:02:01+p*02:01:01:01
# 6 p*02:01:01:01+p*02:01:02:01 p*02:01:02:01+p*02:01:01:01


# messed row in y per op comment:

y <- rbind(y, data.frame(c = "p*02:01:01:01+p*02:01:01:01",
                    d = "p*02:01:01:01+p*02:01:13"))

y$c == y$d


library(stringr)

y$c<- stringr::str_split(y$c, "\\+")
y$d<- stringr::str_split(y$d, "\\+")

sapply(seq_along(y$c), function(i) {
  setequal(y$c[[i]], y$d[[i]])
  })

[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE
```

To work with data in modified post, this is what I could come up with.

First, I recreated your file:

## using example data from modified question:

```
testFile <- tempfile()

cat("c                            d
p*02:01:01:01, p*02:01:02:01 p*02:01:02:01, p*02:01:01:01
p*02:01:01:01, p*02:01:02:01 p*02:01:02:01, p*02:01:01:01
p*02:01:01:01, p*02:01:02:01 p*02:01:02:01, p*02:01:01:01
p*02:01:01:01, p*02:01:02:01 p*02:01:02:01, p*02:01:01:01
p*02:01:01:01, p*02:01:02:01 p*02:01:02:01, p*02:01:01:01
p*02:01:01:01, p*02:01:02:01 p*02:01:02:01, p*02:01:01:01
p*02:01:01:01, p*02:01:01:01    p*02:01:01:01, p*02:01:13
p*02:134, p*02:01:01:01 p*02:01:01:01, p*02:01:13
p*01:01:01:01, p*02:01:01:01 p*01:01:01:01, p*02:01:01:01\n",
           file = testFile)

y1 <- read.csv(testFile, skip = 1, header = FALSE, 
               as.is=TRUE)
head(y1)

##              V1                           V2             V3
## 1 p*02:01:01:01  p*02:01:02:01 p*02:01:02:01  p*02:01:01:01
## 2 p*02:01:01:01  p*02:01:02:01 p*02:01:02:01  p*02:01:01:01
## 3 p*02:01:01:01  p*02:01:02:01 p*02:01:02:01  p*02:01:01:01
## 4 p*02:01:01:01  p*02:01:02:01 p*02:01:02:01  p*02:01:01:01
## 5 p*02:01:01:01  p*02:01:02:01 p*02:01:02:01  p*02:01:01:01
## 6 p*02:01:01:01  p*02:01:02:01 p*02:01:02:01  p*02:01:01:01
```

First I'll eliminate any whitespace at beginning or end of vectors:

```
y1[] <- lapply(y1, str_trim, side="both")
```

Then split the middle and cbind the two other columns into "c" and "d" :

```
y1$c <- cbind(y1$V1, 
              str_split_fixed(y1$V2, pattern = " ", n=2)[,1])
y1$d <- cbind(y1$V3, 
              str_split_fixed(y1$V2, pattern = " ", n=2)[,2])
```

Then we will slightly modify the original script to work with matrices in a data.frame:

```
sapply(seq_along(y1$c[,1]), function(i) {
setequal(y1$c[i,], y1$d[i,])
})
```

and get:

```
## [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: This formula doesn't work if the lengths of characters are different between the 2 columns. For example p*02:01:01:01+p*02:01:01:01 vs p*02:01:01:01+p*02:01:13 should be FALSE but the result is TRUE. Can you suggest an adjustment to the code?

Comment: Yeah... i was afraid that was what you wanted. Can you provide an example with different example combinations?

Comment: I tried to use setequal which should do what you probably have in mind. My first answer was completely boneheaded - should have used set functions to start with.

Comment: Your updated code works for dataframes but does not work for imported csv file - I had the same problem using the mapply function. Here is an dataframe with different sample combinations:

Comment: > y <- rbind(y, data.frame(c = "p*02:01:01:01+p*02:01:01:01",
+                          d = "p*02:01:01:01+p*02:01:13"))

Comment: > y <- rbind(y, data.frame(c = "p*02:134+p*02:01:01:01",
+                          d = "p*02:01:01:01+p*02:01:13"))

Comment: > y <- rbind(y, data.frame(c = "p*01:01:01:01+p*02:01:01:01",
+                          d = "p*01:01:01:01+p*02:01:01:01"))

Comment: > sapply(seq_along(y$c), function(i) {
+     setequal(y$c[[i]], y$d[[i]])
+ })
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE Results are correct for data frame but incorrect when tested on an imported csv file.

Comment: Can you show the results of the head function on your data.frame and the imported csv file? The example you gave looks to me like it will result in 4 columns, in which case the code will not work unless you concatnate each 2 colmn grouping together.